# Vaadin upload component receiveUpload() method

Tags: java, vaadin

I want to upload a recorded file in vaadin. I am using the upload component of vaadin. But the problem is that I dont want to show the file dialog, rather I would like to fire events to upload component from my own buttons. I have written a class which is extended by Upload component and called its fireUploadSuccess() method, this event is successfully fired. But I want to invoke the receiveUpload() method manually, I mean by firing some event from my own button to invoke this method. Any solution friends ?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Normally, in the base Upload Class, when the fireUploadSuccess() is called, the uploadSucceeded method of the attached class is normally called.

If you really changed the method, you maybe forgot the `super()` statement ?

Could you also please show us an example of your modified class if you can

Answer (score 0):

here is a process that i used.

i created a custom class named MyFileReceive which implements `Receiver` interface of `Upload.java` file. There i override the method `receiveUpload()` and did what i want to do when uploaded file is received. Put the instance of MyFileReceiver class into the constructor of Upload class. Hope it will work..

```
    public class MyUI extends UI{
       private MyUI.MyFileReceiver receiver = new MyUI.MyFileReceiver();
       private Upload upload;
       protected void init(VaadinRequest vaadinRequest) {
            .............
            .......................
            upload = new Upload(null, receiver);
            upload.addSucceededListener((SucceededEvent event) -> {
            //Do what you want to do
    });
    public class MyReceiver implements Receiver {
        @Override
        public OutputStream receiveUpload(String filename, String mimeType) {
        //do what you want to do when receive upload
        }
    }
}
```